# ODE solver producing runtime error - not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab

I can't figure out why the ODE solver wont run.

The function is called using

```
[t,s]=ode45(ODE1,[0,2],[0,0,0,0]);
```

It results in
"Not enough input arguments. Error in ODE1 (line 9)"
x_1 = y(2);

```
function dydt = ODE1(t,y)
```

`b = .01;
g = 9.806;
A = 2.5;
B = .25;
C = .13;

x_1 = y(2);

x_2 = f(t)/A - (b/A)*y(2)+B^2*cos(y(3))^2*f(t)/(A^2*C+A*B^2*cos(y(3))^2)...
    -B^2*b*y(2)*cos(y(3))^2/(A^2*C+A*B^2*cos(y(3))^2)...
    -B^2*g*sin(y(3))*cos(y(3))/(A*C+B^2*cos(y(3))^2)...
    +B^3*y(4)^2*sin(y(3))*cos(y(3))^2/(A^2*C+A*B^2*cos(y(3))^2)...
    +B/A*y(4)^2*sin(y(3));

x_3 = y(4);

x_4 = -B*f(t)*cos(y(3))/(A*C+B^2*cos(y(3))^2)...
    +B*b*y(2)*cos(y(3))/(A*C+B^2*cos(y(3))^2)...
    +A*B*g*sin(y(3))/(A*C+B^2*cos(y(3))^2)...
    -B^2*y(4)^2*sin(y(3))*cos(y(3))/(A*C+B^2*cos(y(3))^2);

dydt = [x_1;x_2;x_3;x_4];
end

function y = f(t)

if(t<2)
    y = 1;
else
    y = 0;
end
end`

Comment: I don't think it's the same.

Comment: Change `[t,s]=ode45(ODE1,[0,2],[0,0,0,0]);` to `[t,s]=ode45(@ODE1,[0,2],[0,0,0,0]);` and see what happens.  You need to pass a *function handle*; having `ODE1` sitting there without an `@` will call the function without arguments,